# Understanding the Wasm (WebAssembly) prototype

Tags: javascript, webassembly

In Chrome, the Wasm prototype has four functions:
1) `instantiateModule`
2) `instantiateModuleFromAsm`
3) `verifyFunction`
4) `verifyModule`

Where can I find the appropriate documentation on what they do and how I should call them?

PS:
I have been able to get something from the tests here: https://github.com/WebAssembly/v8-native-prototype/blob/master/test/mjsunit/wasm/asm-wasm.js

PPS:
Also asked here: https://github.com/WebAssembly/v8-native-prototype/issues/111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted on the [v8-native-prototype](https://github.com/WebAssembly/v8-native-prototype/)'s home page, that repo is obsolete as development now happens directly in V8. Chrome canary uses a different API from the old one in that repo.

The precise web API is still being developed in [the design repo](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/), you can see a precise description in [JS.md](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md). It might change some more in the future.

**March 2017 update:** the MVP API has now [reached consensus](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webassembly/2017Feb/0002.html) and will not be broken in the future. The API from the original question has been changed substantially since then! New APIs are likely to be added post-MVP.

If you want to see the details from V8 you can look at the [source code for wasm](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master/src/wasm/) as well as its [cctest](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master/test/cctest/wasm/), [unittest](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master/test/unittests/wasm/), and [mjsunit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master/test/mjsunit/wasm/) tests.

Comment: Thanks JF, I did see that the page became obsolete, but I was confused because of the function I could see in my Chrome install. Would you also suggest that, while the API is in development, I would use the polyfill instead?

Comment: I'd recommend using the latest API. I think it's getting closer to something stable, and the functionality / spelling might change but only in ways that should be easy to fix. It should be possible to target different versions as they evolve. We've talked about doing that for webassembly.github.io/demo so tracking that repo could give you a good heads up.